# Why does Vite throw 404 on production on javascript files that don't have type=module attribute in Netlify?

Tags: javascript

I was working on a HTML, JS and CSS vanilla project with vite and as title says, my javascripts files are not found in production when the javascripts file doesn't have the type=module attribute, I was using netlify as hosting.

When my javascripts file are like this:

```
<script src="./js/hamburgerMenu.js"></script>
```

I got the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:4173/js/hamburgerMenu.js 404 (Not Found)
```

But adding type module attribute fix the error

```
<script src="./js/hamburgerMenu.js"  type="module"></script>
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you perhaps using `import` statements inside your `js/hamburgerMenu.js`? That's one of the ways I can think of why you need `type='module'` attribute on your scripts to specify it's an ES6 JavaScript module. Other than that maybe Netlfiy has some restrictions where you have to have ES6 JS modules?

Comment: Yes, I am using import inside ALL my js files